# I'm trying to detect the color of the cell background in a excel (.xlsx) file using xlrd but I cant seem to do it successfully

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Trying to detect the cell background color in an xlsx excel spreadsheet, but it seems to be not accurate. Please help!!!

```
import xlrd

workbook =xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')

l_colors=[]

c = worksheet.cell(1, 1)

cif = worksheet.cell_xf_index(1,5)

iif = workbook.xf_list[cif]
cbg = iif.background.pattern_colour_index
print(cbg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using

> iif.background.pattern_colour_index

but instead you want

```
get_color(iif.background.background_colour_index)
```

as explained by petraszd in [How to read the Font and Background color in excel using xlrd version 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216433/how-to-read-the-font-and-background-color-in-excel-using-xlrd-version-1-1-0)

He defines this helper:

```
def get_color(color_index):
    return book.colour_map.get(color_index)
```